# nested hashtables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures, hash, dictionary

I want to create the following data-structure with js:

`folders` dictionary: `folder-id(guid) : ==> pages dictionary`

`pages` array: `page-position(int) : ==> files dictionary`

`files` dictionary: `file-id(guid) : ==> file object`

I want to know at each time how many items are in each collection.

How would you suggest me to implemet this in JS ?

Should I use array or object with dynamically added properties?

Comment: Actually, JSON is just a serializing format.

Comment: Are the keys all primitives? I.e., can all keys be converted into strings correctly?

Comment: yes, keys are strings and ints

Comment: @pimvdb I was asking because his question looked like he didn't, and if he didn't I would have explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the classes as follows.

```
function HashTable() {
    var content = {};
    var count = 0;
    this.Add = function(key, value) {
        if (content.hasOwnProperty(key)) throw new Error("Key already exist");
        content[key] = value;
        count++;
    };
    this.Set = function(key, value) {
        if (!content.hasOwnProperty(key)) count++;
          content[key] = value;
    };
    this.Get = function(key) {
        if (!content.hasOwnProperty(key)) throw new Error("No such key");
        return content[key];
    };
    this.AllKeys = function() {
        var keys = [];
        for (a in content) {
            keys.push(a);
        }
        return keys;
    };
    this.Count = function() {
        return count;
    };
    this.Remove = function(key) {
        if (!content.hasOwnProperty(key)) throw new Error("No such key");
        delete content[key];
        count--;
    };
}


// Then you can use it as follows

var folders = new HashTable();
folders.Add(1, 10);
alert(folders.Count());
alert(folders.Get(1));
folders.Remove(1);
alert(folders.Count());
```

It gives you a more rigid and OOP approach.

**Edit**

This ensures that your keys are unique, gives you count at any time and accepts integers and
strings as keys.

Comment: How can I use and write this ctor not in the global scope?

Comment: @EladBenda Put the definition in the global scope. Then you can instantiate it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write it out:

```
var folders = {
    'folder1-guid': [
        {'file1-guid': 'file1-content'},
        {'file2-guid': 'file1-content'}
    ]
};
```

Alternatively, create [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instances and assign the properties to them.

Comment: +1 And "how many items" could be done using `Object.keys(obj).length`.

Comment: Should I use array or object with dynamically added properties?

Comment: Use an array if you want to express a (potentially ordered) set of elements, and an object if you want to have a mapping of strings to elements.